# connecting an Ethernet which needs a password and a user name?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, internet, ethernet

I have an account through a wired network (Ethernet) internet provider - a person that have an internet LAN and share it with neighbours in exchange with money - every one of us have an account and a password , when we need to access the internet we open the Firefox page and the welcome page of this provider will appear asking us to enter the password and the user name.

after accepting password and user name it will gave you the ability to access internet and the welcome page will not appear again unless you logout or unplug the network .

The problem is : I need to enter this network by a script through the terminal , because some times I leave home and an analytical program which needs internet is working and the internet for any reason unplugged - a network regular deactivation- I am not there physically to enter the password and the account again.

I need to write a script if the network go off it enter the password and the user account automatically when it came back to life.